# Change ActionBar text color after inheriting Theme.AppCompat.DayNight

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-darkmode

I'm implementing support for dark mode. But after I changed Theme parent to *Theme.AppCompat.DayNight*, text in Action Bar is black (black in day mode and white in dark mode). I want the text to be always white. I tried to change text color in styles.xml (values and values-night)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

but it is not working. The title text color in ActionBar is still black.

Comment: works for me <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the ActionBar in your theme you should use the `actionBarStyle` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/....</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/...</item>
</style>
```

If you are using the `Toolbar` API, you can also use

```
 <Toolbar
   app:titleTextColor="@color/...."
   ../>
```

Instead with the Material Components Library and the `Toolbar` API you can use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/my_Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name=my_Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best and easiest solution is @MagogCZ's answer =>

**"works for me `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`"** **– MagogCZ**

Answer (score 0):

need to use `actionBarTheme` and not `actionBarStyle` for text Color